# How to upload several photos using aw3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, graphql, prisma

I use `react native` and backend was built with `Prisma` and `GraphQL` (`Apollo` Server).
I don't store image data to Prisma but to `aw3`.

The problem is I want to upload several images at once to my app. So I make image column of Prisma Array [], not String.

But as using aw3, I can upload only one image at once. So even if I make image column as Array, I can't upload several images at once as Array using `aw3`.

When I searched people suggest 3 options in order to upload multiple files by aw3.

1. multi-thread
2. multi-processing
3. zip upload (amazon-lambda)

In my case(to upload files as `Array`),
which option is most advisable?
And can you teach me the way of doing that?

My backend code:

```
export const uploadToS3 = async (file, userId, folderName) => {
  const { filename, createReadStream } = await file;
  const readStream = createReadStream();
  const objectName = `${folderName}/${userId}-${Date.now()}-${filename}`;
  const { Location } = await new AWS.S3()
    .upload({
      Bucket: "chungchunonuploads",
      Key: objectName,
      ACL: "public-read",
      Body: readStream,
    })
    .promise();
  return Location;
};
```

Comment: Are you uploading from the client or from the server? Either way you can upload all the files first (just Promise.all or something like that) and then call backend or update DB entity and etc.

Comment: @Danila
From the server. I edit my post including my code. This code above can't make Array. can you teach me more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to resolve multiple file upload promises with `Promise.all`. Let us refactor our code and split it into 2 functions.

```js
// Assume that we have list of all files to upload
const filesToUpload = [file1, file2, file3, fileN];

export const uploadSingleFileToS3 = async (file, userId, folderName) => {
  const { filename, createReadStream } = await file;
  const readStream = createReadStream();
  const objectName = `${folderName}/${userId}-${Date.now()}-${filename}`;
  const response = await new AWS.S3().upload({
    Bucket: "chungchunonuploads",
    Key: objectName,
    ACL: "public-read",
    Body: readStream,
  });

  return response;
};

const uploadMultipleFilesToS3 = async (filesToUpload, userId, folderName) => {
  const uploadPromises = filesToUpload.map((file) => {
    return uploadSingleFileToS3(file, userId, folderName);
  });

  // Array containing all  uploaded files data
  const uploadResult = await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

  // Add logic here to update the database with  Prisma ORM
};

// Call uploadMultipleFilesToS3 with all required parameters
```